# How to display particular client name in next template using `meteor Js`?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I need help for how to display particular client name in next template using meteor js. Here is my code verify and give me any suggestion .Route template is also placed see once.

```
template:


 <template name="clientedit">
    <table>
            <tr>
            {{#each clientList}}
                <td>{{client}}</td>
            {{/each}}
            </tr>
                 </table>
</template>
    <template name="client">
            {{#each clientList}}
               <tr class="clientrow">
                <td >{{client}} <button class="openpopup">open</button></td>
              </tr>
            {{/each}}
           </template> 
            clientJs:
            Template.clientedit.clientList = function () 
             {
                console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> clientList "+H_client.find().count());     
               return H_client.find();         
            };

            Template.client.events({
                'click .openpopup':function(e,t){

                     console.log("Client Name :"+ e.target.innerHTML);
                     e.preventDefault();         
                     Session.set('menuchange' , 'clientedit');

                }
            });
```

Comment: What does your data look for a single `H_client` document? Like what properties does it have?

Comment: client have some data but i want display only client name if i click open button it renders clientlist template in that template i have to display client name of particular client click open button@Firo

Comment: Yeah, so is there a name property on an `H_client` document? Or a `displayName`? Is the property you are attempting to display just called `name` (in the actual Mongo Collection)?

Comment: yes just name of that client name@Firo

Comment: Once client register that client details are display in a table format in that table if we click client particular name (open button)it renders a new template with client name.@Firo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
template:
{{#each clientList}}
   <tr class="clientrow">
    {{! When we loop through "clientList" each new "this" is an actual "H_client"
        so we can just grab the name off of it! }}
    <td >{{name}} <button class="openpopup">open</button></td>
  </tr>
{{/each}}


Template.client.events({
    'click .openpopup':function(e,t){

         // notice, we can just grab this.name since this event happens inside the DOM context
         console.log("Client Name :"+ this.name);
         e.preventDefault();         
         Session.set('menuchange' , 'clientedit');

    }
});
```

So here we only changed two things. One was to access the `name` property off of a single `H_client` document. The second was to access the `name` via the context in the event.

Comment: ok it is comming i want display that name in next template how to get that name@Firo

Comment: @user3206372 it kind of depends. Is the template a different page/route? An easy way would be to save `this` as a session variable inside the click event. Then with a `helper` other templates could access this data.

Comment: @user3206372 so the client edit template just does the same thing (displays all users?)